# Setting a variable as a class (using set classes) in a region template

Tags: 8, theming

I am attempting to set a common class if any preface region in my theme appears. I am trying to render this with a variable using `set classes = []` in the region template in my theme.

So far I have set a variable in a preprocess region like this:

```
function gratis_preprocess_region(&$vars) {
  // Check to see if any of the preface regions have content and if so
  // Set a common var for use as a class in the region template.
  if (!empty($vars['page']['preface_first']) || !empty($vars['page']['preface_second']) || !empty($vars['page']['preface_third'])) {
    $vars['preface_region'] = '';
  }
}
```

Then in my theme's region template I attempt to render the variable within the `set classes` area.

```
  set classes = [
    'region',
    'region-' ~ region|clean_class,
    region == preface_region ? 'region-preface'
  ]
```

I am pretty sure I am not doing this the correct way though and it does not work.

Comment: Sorry I think that I miss something, where is defined `$vars['page']`? By default there is no `$vars['page']` in `preprocess_region`.  If 'preface_first' is a block, maybe you want `$vars['elements']['preface_first']`.

Comment: I already get that kind of class for any of the preface regions but I am trying to set a common class if it's any of the three preface regions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the way to do this was to create a theme hook for all preface regions and then it can have its own template. So first I create an alter preprocess function in my theme's .theme file.

```
function MYTHEME_theme_suggestions_region_alter(&$suggestions, $vars, $hook) {
  // Print the $vars.
  kint($vars);

  // Define a var for the #region. 
  $preface = $vars['elements']['#region'];

  // Now check for any of the three preface regions and create a theme hook. 
  if ($preface == 'preface_first' || $preface == 'preface_second' || $preface == 'preface_third') {
    $suggestions[] = 'region' .  '__' . 'preface';
  }
}
```

Next, voila, when I look at Twig debug, I see a suggestion for my new theme hook.

```
   * region--preface.html.twig >> **** This is the new template from the alter
   * region--preface-second.html.twig
   x region.html.twig
```

Now I can create a common template for all three preface regions with `region--preface.html.twig`.

Then in the new template, I print the classes like so:

```
 {%
set classes = [
'region',
'region-preface',
'region-' ~ region|clean_class
]
%}
```

This gives me exactly what I set out to do and prints this HTML:

```
<div class="region region-preface region-preface-second">
```

Now I can use `.region-preface` for common theming / HTML for any of the three the preface regions.