# How to make a theme hook suggestion for menu according to region?

Tags: 8, theming

I'm placing the **same menu block in two different regions** whereas different html markup for the list is needed. So analog to my previous question ["How to make a theme hook suggestion for blocks according to region?"](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/192616/how-to-make-a-theme-hook-suggestion-for-blocks-according-to-region/) I need to know, **how to get the current region** inside the function MYMODULE_theme_suggestions_menu_alter, to add my own suggestion.

Comment: If your menu is a block you can add suggestion add block level, as described here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/192616/how-to-make-a-theme-hook-suggestion-for-blocks-according-to-region?lq=1, if you want to be specific just check if your block is a menu before add suggestion,

Comment: Have a look here, I was querying regions to implement some better theming. Not sure if this will help: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/193701/697

Comment: I need to alter the ul and nested li of the menu, so hooking at block or region level won't help, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

[Joery Lemmens](https://www.drupal.org/u/flyke) posted an [answer](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/theme-development/2017-07-13/extra-template-name-suggestions-for-main-menus-based-on#comment-12627124) to a similar [question](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/theme-development/2017-07-13/extra-template-name-suggestions-for-main-menus-based-on) on Drupal's forums:

```
use Drupal\block\Entity\Block;

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 *
 * Pass block region value to content so this can be used in
 * MYTHEME_theme_suggestions_menu_alter.
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['elements']['#id'])) {
    $region = Block::load($variables['elements']['#id'])->getRegion();
    $variables['content']['#attributes']['region'] = $region;
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 *
 * Provide region based menu suggestions.
 */
function MYTHEME_theme_suggestions_menu_alter(&$suggestions, array $variables) {
  if (isset($variables['attributes']['region'])) {
    $suggestions[] = 'menu__' . $variables['menu_name'] . '__' . $variables['attributes']['region'];
  }
}
```

All credit to Joery for this elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hacky solution, but it worked for me.
Only difference is that I needed to do it to search forms, but it should be equally applicable to your situation.

```
use Drupal\block\Entity\Block;

/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */
function MODULE_theme_suggestions_form_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {

  if($variables['element']['#form_id'] === 'search_block_form') {

    if(isset($variables['element']['#id']) && !empty($variables['element']['#id'])) {

      if($variables['element']['#id'] === 'search-block-form') {
        $block = Block::load('searchform');
      }
      else if($variables['element']['#id'] === 'search-block-form--2') {
        $block = Block::load('searchform_2');
      }

      if(isset($block) && !empty($block)) {
        $suggestions[] = 'form__' . $block->getRegion();
        $suggestions[] = 'form__' . $block->getRegion() . '_searchform';
      }
    }
  }

  return $suggestions;
}
```

---

**Explanation of code:**
*Remember to change the function name to use the correct hook!*

```
if($variables['element']['#form_id'] === 'search_block_form') {
  ...
}
```

I do this, so that my suggestions only affect the search block form, you should change this to a check for the right menu, so your suggestions only affect the menu you need it for.

```
if(isset($variables['element']['#id']) && !empty($variables['element']['#id'])) {
  ...
}
```

This is just to prevent errors in case I hit a form that doesn't have an id.

```
if($variables['element']['#id'] === 'search-block-form') {
  $block = Block::load('searchform');
}
else if($variables['element']['#id'] === 'search-block-form--2') {
  $block = Block::load('searchform_2');
}
```

This is what I consider the "hacky" bit, basically I check for the id's of the forms (in this case search-block-form and search-block-form--2), and then proceed to load the appropriate block (the block id's used for loading the blocks, are just the machine names give to the blocks).

```
if(isset($block) && !empty($block)) {
  $suggestions[] = 'form__' . $block->getRegion();
  $suggestions[] = 'form__' . $block->getRegion() . '_searchform';
}
```

Here I just add the suggestions, I add 2 suggestions, but you can probably justify only adding one.

---

I really hope this helps, feel free to suggest changes to my code.